# A strange generics edge case with Mockito.when() and generic type inference

Tags: java, generics, mockito

I'm writing a test case that uses a `java.beans.PropertyDescriptor` using Mockito, and I want to mock the behavior of `getPropertyType()` to return an arbitrary `Class<?>` object (in my case, `String.class`). Normally, I would do that by just invoking:

```
// we already did an "import static org.mockito.Mockito.*"
when(mockDescriptor.getPropertyType()).thenReturn(String.class);
```

However, oddly, this does not compile:

```
cannot find symbol method thenReturn(java.lang.Class<java.lang.String>)
```

But when I specify the type parameter instead of depending on inference:

```
Mockito.<Class<?>>when(mockDescriptor.getPropertyType()).thenReturn(String.class);
```

everything is hunky dory. Why can't the compiler correctly infer the return type of when() in this case? I have never had to specify the parameter before like that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`PropertyDescriptor#getPropertyType()` returns an object of `Class<?>`, where the `?` means "this is a type, but I don't know what it is".  Let's call this type "X".  So `when(mockDescriptor.getPropertyType())` creates an `OngoingStubbing<Class<X>>`, whose method `thenReturn(Class<X>)` can only accept objects of `Class<X>`.  But the compiler doesn't know what type this "X" is, so it will complain about you passing in a `Class` of *any* type.  I think this is the same reason the compiler complains about calling `add(...)` on a `Collection<?>`.

When you explicitly specify `Class<?>` for the type on the `when` method, you're not saying that `mockDescriptor.getPropertyType()` returns a `Class<?>`, you're saying that `when` returns an `OngoingStubbing<Class<?>>`.  Then, the compiler checks to make sure whatever you're passing into `when` is of a type that matches `Class<?>`; since `getPropertyType()` returns the "`Class<X>`" I mentioned earlier, it of course matches the `Class<?>` you specified.

So basically

```
// the inferred type is Class<"some type">
Mockito.when(mockDescriptor.getPropertyType())

// the specified type is Class<"any type">
Mockito.<Class<?>>when(mockDescriptor.getPropertyType())
```

In my IDE, the error message for your original code is

```
The method thenReturn(Class<capture#1-of ?>) in the type OngoingStubbing<Class<capture#1-of ?>> is not applicable for the arguments (Class<String>)
```

That `capture#1-of ?` is the "X" I described above.