# How do I get typeName() from a mock object in a JUnit test?

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, propertydescriptor

This is one of the strangest methods I've had to mock. I need to somehow reconcile my unit test with the following code:

```
protected void sub(Object obj) {
    try {
        BeanInfo beanInfo = getBeanInfo(obj);
        for (PropertyDescriptor pb : beanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors()) {
            String fieldType = pd.getPropertyType.getTypeName();
            System.out.println(fieldType);
        }
    } catch (InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It LOOKS like it might be a straightforward unit test (I moved getBeanInfo() to a separate method so I could mock it without tripping over Introspector). However, it will always throw an InvocationTargetException whenever I get to getTypeName(). Is there a way to somehow mock a PropertyDescriptor's property type? I found a solution here on stackoverflow, but it hasn't helped much.

[A strange generics edge case with Mockito.when() and generic type inference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952629/a-strange-generics-edge-case-with-mockito-when-and-generic-type-inference)

Here's the code for how I mock the BenInfo object:

```
@Test
public void testSub() {
    ClientViewer cv = mock(ClientViewer.class); // The class that I'm testing.
    when(cv.getBeanInfo(mockValue)).thenReturn(mockBeanInfo);

    // Rest of the test.
}
```

The mockValue object is just a generic object. The mockBeanInfo object is pretty self-explanatory. This code does work. The problem is mocking the PropertyDescriptor name.

Here's getBeanInfo():

```
protected BeanInfo getBeanInfo(Object obj) {
    BeanInfo beanInfo = null;

    try {
        Class cls = obj.getClas();
        beanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(cls);
    } catch (IntrospectionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return beanInfo;
}
```

And finally mockBeanInfo:

```
@Mock private java.beans.BeanInfo mockBeanInfo;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Let's talk about what a Java Bean is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3295517/1768232):

> 1. All properties private (use [getters/setters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method))
> 2. A public [no-argument constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullary_constructor)
> 3. Implements [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html).

In other words, a Bean is just a data structure. It has no behavior, no unintended consequences that you want to prevent from happening with a mock. In other words, you shouldn't be mocking `BeanInfo` **at all**.

However, you do want to ensure that your class is doing the right things with your BeanInfo objects. You want to get **real** `BeanInfo` objects in **both your production code and your test**, because it's a data structure. So, what you really need is a way to get access to these real `BeanInfo` objects in your test method.

Note: You're not going to be able to avoid using the real `Introspector` here, because your application needs the data it provides.

Here's how I would fix your problem:

1. Refactor your `getBeanInfo()` behavior to use a separate class, `BeanInfoProvider`:

   ```
   public class SimpleBeanInfoProvider implements BeanInfoProvider {
     public BeanInfo getBeanInfo(Object obj) {
       BeanInfo beanInfo = null;

       try {
         Class cls = obj.getClass();
         beanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(cls);
       } catch (IntrospectionException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
       }

       return beanInfo;
     }
   }
   ```
2. Inject this behavior into `ClientViewer`, probably by adding a constructor argument.

   ```
   private final BeanInfoProvider provider;

   public ClientViewer(..., BeanInfoProvider provider) {
     // snip
     this.provider = provider;
   }
   ```
3. Change your methods that use `BeanInfo` to use this `BeanInfoProvider`

   ```
   protected void sub(Object obj) {
     try {
       BeanInfo beanInfo = provider.getBeanInfo(obj);
       // snip
   ```
4. Make an implementation of `BeanInfoProvider` that generates **spies** and allows you to access them. Note: you need to cache the `BeanInfo` spy to make sure you get the same one inside `ClientViewer` and your test method.

   ```
   public class SpyBeanInfoProvider implements BeanInfoProvider {
     private final BeanInfoProvider delegate;
     private final Map<Class<?>, BeanInfo> spyMap = new HashMap<>(); 

     public SpyBeanInfoProvider(BeanInfoProvider delegate) {
       this.delegate = delegate;
     }

     @Override
     public BeanInfo getBeanInfo(Object obj) {
       Class<?> klass = obj.getClass();
       if(!spyMap.containsKey(klass)) {
         BeanInfo info = spy(delegate.getBeanInfo(obj));
         spyMap.put(klass, info);
         return info;
       } else {
         return spyMap.get(obj);
       }
     }
   }
   ```
5. Inject this into your test

   ```
   private BeanInfoProvider makeBeanInfoProvider() {
     return new SpyBeanInfoProvider(new IntrospectorBeanInfoProvider());
   }

   @Test
   public void testSub() {
     BeanInfoProvider provider = makeBeanInfoProvider();
     ClientViewer viewer = new ClientViewer(makeBeanInfoProvider());
     viewer.sub(obj);
     BeanInfo spy = provider.getBeanInfo(obj);

     // Now do your test
     verify(spy).getPropertyDescriptors();
     // etc.
   }
   ```

This will allow you to have access to the `BeanInfo` objects that get generated - because they are real data structures, implemented as partial mocks, and you won't get these `InvocationTargetException`s anymore.

Comment: I appreciate the idea, but it's not at all related to the problem I'm getting. I already have a function to generate a BeinInfo object, and I'm using that to spawn a mock BeanInfo object in my unit test. I'm doing it this way because I couldn't find a way to mock the Introspector class. My question is how to mock a property descriptor of the mockBeanInfo object and get its property type and type name without throwing an exception.